# Php, Html5, xampp

Tags: php, sql, html, xampp

I was trying execute this PHP file that I have in XAMPP. I am trying to update the data to the database through a form, when I enter the info and give submit button the page just reloads or I get the message all fields are required though I fill up all. Give an it a check to the code. The data I enter just doesn't get updated to the database. I've checked with the database name and table name that if I am mentioning it properly and also I've tried just checking that if I am able to connect to the database. In that case it is getting connected to the database properly.but just not updating the info the table.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="main">
            <div class="icon-head-wthree">
                    <h2><span class="fa fa-heart t-w3" aria-hidden="true"></span></h2>
                    <h4>Donor?</h4>
                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="district" placeholder="District" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone 1" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="p1" placeholder="Phone 2">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="pincode" placeholder="Pincode" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="bg " placeholder="Blood Group" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-add">

                            <input type="text" name="add1 " placeholder="Address 1" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-add">

                            <input type="text" name="add2 " placeholder="Address 2" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check" checked="checked">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        <label class="cont">I agree to the terms and conditions 
                              </label>
                        <div class="btnn">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit Request </button><br>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </form>
        <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $db= 'bank';

if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['district']) && !empty($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['Phone']) && !empty($_POST['p1']) && !empty($_POST['pincode']) && !empty($_POST['bg']) && !empty($_POST['add1']) && !empty($_POST['add2'])) 
{ //added
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $city= $_POST['city'];
    $district= $_POST['district'];
    $state= $_POST['state'];
    $Phone= $_POST['Phone'];
    $p1= $_POST['p1'];
    $pincode= $_POST['pincode'];
    $bg= $_POST['bg'];
    $add1= $_POST['add1'];
    $add2= $_POST['add2'];
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',$db) or die(mysql_error());


    $sql="INSERT INTO donor VALUES('$name','$lname','$city','$district','$state','$Phone','$p1','$pincode','$bg','$add1','$add2')";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

     if($result){
    echo "Account Successfully Created";
    } else {
    echo "Failure!";
    }


}

else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
} 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your input tag names has spaces like name="bg " instead of  name="bg". Same case for inputs - add1, and add2.

Updated code below. It should be working fine.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="main">
            <div class="icon-head-wthree">
                    <h2><span class="fa fa-heart t-w3" aria-hidden="true"></span></h2>
                    <h4>Donor?</h4>
                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="district" placeholder="District" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone 1" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="p1" placeholder="Phone 2">
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="pincode" placeholder="Pincode" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                            <input type="text" name="bg" placeholder="Blood Group" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-add">

                            <input type="text" name="add1" placeholder="Address 1" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-left-to-add">

                            <input type="text" name="add2" placeholder="Address 2" >
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check" checked="checked">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        <label class="cont">I agree to the terms and conditions 
                              </label>
                        <div class="btnn">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit Request </button><br>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </form>
        <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $db= 'bank';

if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['district']) && !empty($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['Phone']) && !empty($_POST['p1']) && !empty($_POST['pincode']) && !empty($_POST['bg']) && !empty($_POST['add1']) && !empty($_POST['add2'])) 
{ //added
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $city= $_POST['city'];
    $district= $_POST['district'];
    $state= $_POST['state'];
    $Phone= $_POST['Phone'];
    $p1= $_POST['p1'];
    $pincode= $_POST['pincode'];
    $bg= $_POST['bg'];
    $add1= $_POST['add1'];
    $add2= $_POST['add2'];
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',$db) or die(mysql_error());


    $sql="INSERT INTO donor VALUES('$name','$lname','$city','$district','$state','$Phone','$p1','$pincode','$bg','$add1','$add2')";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

     if($result){
    echo "Account Successfully Created";
    } else {
    echo "Failure!";
    }


}

else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
} 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

as the last answer remove the white space in (blood group : name="bg", address1: name="add1", address2: name="add2") some of name of input tag.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="main">
        <div class="icon-head-wthree">
                <h2><span class="fa fa-heart t-w3" aria-hidden="true"></span></h2>
                <h4>Donor?</h4>
                </div>
                                <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                                <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" >
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                        <input type="text" name="district" placeholder="District" >
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                        <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State" >
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                        <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone 1" >
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                        <input type="text" name="p1" placeholder="Phone 2">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                        <input type="text" name="pincode" placeholder="Pincode" >
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-left-to-w3l">

                        <input type="text" name="bg " placeholder="Blood Group" > // remoce white space
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-left-to-add">

                        <input type="text" name="add1 " placeholder="Address 1" > // remoce white space
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-left-to-add">

                        <input type="text" name="add2 " placeholder="Address 2" > // remoce white space
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check" checked="checked">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    <label class="cont">I agree to the terms and conditions 
                          </label>
                    <div class="btnn">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit Request </button><br>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) == "submit"){
$db= 'bank';

if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['district']) && !empty($_POST['state']) && !empty($_POST['Phone']) && !empty($_POST['p1']) && !empty($_POST['pincode']) && !empty($_POST['bg']) && !empty($_POST['add1']) && !empty($_POST['add2'])) 
{ //added
$name=$_POST['name'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$city= $_POST['city'];
$district= $_POST['district'];
$state= $_POST['state'];
$Phone= $_POST['Phone'];
$p1= $_POST['p1'];
$pincode= $_POST['pincode'];
$bg= $_POST['bg'];
$add1= $_POST['add1'];
$add2= $_POST['add2'];
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',$db) or die(mysql_error());


$sql="INSERT INTO donor VALUES('$name','$lname','$city','$district','$state','$Phone','$p1','$pincode','$bg','$add1','$add2')";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 if($result){
echo "Account Successfully Created";
} else {
echo "Failure!";
}


}

else {
echo "All fields are required!";
}    } 
  ?>
```

this code copy and paste.

and when ever you use the isset function please user the post's value to perfect condition like

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) == "submit")

if you have many button in one page then it will very help full thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write the INSERT INTO statement in two ways.

The first way specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

> Step 1:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

If you are adding values for all the columns of the table, you do not need to specify the column names in the SQL query. However, make sure the order of the values is in the same order as the columns in the table. The INSERT INTO syntax would be as follows:

> Step 2:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

And in your code I suppose you are trying to use the second method but you are not using all the column. (For example **id** column which may be auto increment )

So change your this insert code

```
INSERT INTO donor VALUES('$name','$lname','$city','$district','$state','$Phone','$p1','$pincode','$bg','$add1','$add2');
```

to **step 1** as I have shown above which looks like shown below.

```
INSERT INTO donor (name, lname, city, district, state, phone, p1, pincode, bg, add1, add2) VALUES('$name','$lname','$city','$district','$state','$Phone','$p1','$pincode','$bg','$add1','$add2');
```